# Redux: Can nested components call action methods?

Tags: javascript, redux, nested, react-redux

I have a page which has roughly following structure in react:

```
<App>
    <Sidebar>
        <MapLayers>
            <Layer id="1" />
            <Layer id="2" />
        </MapLayers>
    </Sidebar>
    <Map />
</App>
```

Right now I have all the state within my components. But this has made my code messy and hard to maintain.
I was looking to use Redux to solve this state management issue. I know that we can use Provider which if I am correct, connects to store and passes down props to child components.

My question is, if some UI element within my Layer component e.g a dropdown raises change event and by that I want to modify my store state, now instead of bubbling this event to Main component and then doing the action, **can nested component directly call action method to do some operation in store?**

Comment: What's stopping you from connecting your "nested component" to redux?

Comment: @Andrew can u plz give an example?

Comment: The way you connect a component to redux is the same, regardless of where the component exists in your component hierarchy. Show us a sample component you have connected to redux. in your current app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you'll have to do is wrap your `<App />` in a `<Provider/>` and then you can connect your inner most components with the redux state using `mapStateToProps` (which connects attributes in the state to props of your component) and `mapDispatchToProps` (which enables your actions to dispatch actions to the reducers to cause state changes)